# Real-Time processing of AmpKit LINK signals in C#

Tags: c#, audio, guitar

I want to start a project to create an iPhone/Android app which acts as a guitar effects pedal, with some other features.
Firstly, I'll need a way of receiving the signals sent from the guitar into the device.
I'd preferably like to handle as much of this as possible with C#.

I was thinking of using something like the AmpKit LINK to handle the guitar input.

Where do I start with this?

Feel free to recommend any other input devices or languages.

Thanks,
Cal.

Input device - Peavey AmpKit LINK:

http://www.soundsliveshop.com/p/Peavey_AmpKit_LiNK/PV-AMPKITLINK?CAWELAID=1830897475&CAGPSPN=pla&gclid=CNnB943RmsECFabMtAod6QgAng

proposed IDE: Xamarin (cross platform (IOS/Android) from C#)

http://xamarin.com/

Comment: you mean something like this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21269072/android-capturing-raw-sound-and-transforming-to-integer-values
?

This is about visuals, but once you capture the raw audio you can manipulate it any way you want

Comment: This question is *way* too broad.  and unlikely to be of use to other users.  Pleaser refer to the FAQ and the section about asking questions.

Comment: The subject area is broad, however the question is quite specific. - I want to know how to use the hardware suggested to be able to process the sound in real time